# c++ how to print utf8 symbol using utf8 hex code?

Tags: c++, utf-8

For example I have utf8 hex code of a symbol which is:

```
e0a4a0
```

how can I use this hex code to print this character `ठ` to a file in c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output each byte separately.

For example if you have:

```
c386
```

You need to convert first byte (first two characters "c3") to int, convert to char and output, then second byte ("86") and also convert and output.

Conversion for this particular case ("c386"):

```
string a="c386";
char b = (a[0] - 'A' + 10) * 16 + a[1] - '0';
char c = (a[2] - '0') * 16 + a[3] - '0';
cout << b << c << endl;
```

"c3" = 44*16 + 3 = 707, "86" = 8*16 + 6 = 134. Convert those int values to char and output them both and you have your character.

Answer (score 1):

I see two approaches you can take:
first is to use it literally as `"ठ"` second is to encode it in escape sequence `\u` or `\x` (both doesn't work, so I don't have an example)

```
std::cout<<"ठ\xe0\xa4\xa0"<<std::endl;
```

But I think that best option for you will be open file in binary mode and simply put those bytes there.

Comment: I'm trying to print but it doesn't print the symbol in just prints a question mark

Comment: @katinas Focus on the goal. Check the bytes in the first file. It could be that you've achieved the goal but you test is faulty.

Comment: @katinas use `xxd`, or similar stuff to check what file really contains